# Using Penelope to convert xml/stardict dictionaries to Bookeen format

Tags: python, xml, makefile, pip, converters

I'm trying to install better dictionaries on my Bookeen Cybook Odyssey Ebook reader. I'm on Windows 10.
Ideally I would like to just download dictionaries for Bookeen which someone else has already converted, but I can't seem to find any.

I found [Penelope](https://github.com/pettarin/penelope) which is a converter tool. I got it installed but not the dependencies. I got some [dictionaries in Stardict format](https://sites.google.com/site/gtonguedict/home/stardict-dictionaries) (can't find any XML ones), but now I can't convert them because I don't know how to install the dependency - "dictzip" which is needed to convert Stardict into Bookeen format.

On Linux you can just type:  `apt-get install dictzip`

On Windows I found a folder with [dictzip](https://github.com/dictzip) in but I'm not sure which package is right. I downloaded [this one](https://github.com/dictzip/dictzip) but I don't know how to run the "INSTALL" file in python (sorry I don't know any Python).

Here is my Penelope command:

```
penelope -i oxford.dict.dz -j stardict -f en -t en -p bookeen -o oxford.bookeen.dict.dz
```

Comment: I managed to install the 1 English dictionary available on this link: https://blog.bookeen.com/2012/01/20/dictionary-beta-tests-go/ but would still like to be able to get the above to work.

Answer (score -1):

Stardict format as understand by penelope should be a zip file with .dict.dz among other files inside it (like .idx). If you have them in one directory you can always zip it by normal means.

Comment: No it needs to be converted to work on a Bookeen device.